# What do you call "xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui""

Tags: xhtml

What do you call "xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui", are they tags?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's an XML namespace alias. It introduces `p` as a shorthand for the namespace `http://primefaces.org/ui` so that from then on:

```
<p:moose>
```

serves as a shorthand for

```
<moose xmlns="http://primefaces.org/ui">
```

Answer (score 3):

They are attributes, the purpose of which is to import XML namespaces.

`html` is the tag.